# How can I react to changes in window size with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this as a way to watch for a window resize event.  However it works very slowly. Can someone advise if they know of some other way that is simple and does not involve a complicated directive. Also would appreciate any suggestions on if the way I am doing it is a good way.

```
 $scope.$watch(($scope) => {
    $scope.isLarge = $window.innerWidth > 650 ? true : false;
    angular.element($window).on('resize', () => {
       $scope.$digest();
    });
    console.log($scope.isLarge);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Working Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/SfJ8c/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="miniapp" ng-controller="AppController" ng-style="style()" resize>window.height: {{windowHeight}}
    <br />window.width: {{windowWidth}}
    <br />
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);

function AppController($scope) {
    /* Logic goes here */
}

app.directive('resize', function ($window) {
    return function (scope, element) {
        var w = angular.element($window);
        scope.getWindowDimensions = function () {
            return {
                'h': w.height(),
                'w': w.width()
            };
        };
        scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
            scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;

            scope.style = function () {
                return {
                    'height': (newValue.h - 100) + 'px',
                    'width': (newValue.w - 100) + 'px'
                };
            };

        }, true);

        w.bind('resize', function () {
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but can you show me how this would work without a directive. That seems like overkill to me to have so many lines. I am looking for the very most simple solution.  Can you also comment on the code that I have and let me know if that is a good or bad way to do it? Thanks